# Ruby, subscribing to PubNub channel does not output any messages

Tags: ruby, pubnub

I'm following the Ruby SDK guide.

I can publish successfully but when trying to subscribe, nothing happens as I try to send a message to the channel from the PubNub console.

When running the code, it finishes and exits. No async is happening.

```
pubnub = Pubnub.new(
  subscribe_key: 'demo', 
  publish_key: 'demo', 
  connect_callback: lambda {|msg| pubnub.publish(channel: 'demo', message: 'Hello from PubNub        Ruby SDK!!', http_sync: true)}
)


pubnub.subscribe(channel: 'demo') do |envelope|
  puts envelope.message
end
```

Comment: Are you keys correct?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both the demo channel and my own. The connect_callback successfully can publish a message to the channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program finishes because main thread ends its work and exits before async code gets messages. Just add some sleep time on the end or run this code in pry console.

Comment: adding the sleep() at the end worked perfectly. Thanks!!